# How to get an integer result for Car Class with strings and integers

Tags: c++, string, class, integer

I am writing a program to do the following:

- The constructor accepts the car’s year and make as arguments and assigns these values to the object’s year and make member variables. The constructor also initializes the speed member variable to 0.
- Appropriate accessor functions are also created to allow values to be retrieved from an object’s year, make and speed member variables.
- The accelerate function adds 5 to the speed member variable each time it is called.  
- The brake function subtracts 5 from the speed member variable each time it is called.

This is what I have as of now, but I am having trouble returning the correct speeds. Any solutions as to why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Car
{
    private:

    int yearModel;
    string make;
    int speed;

    public:

    Car(int, string, int);
    int getSpeed();
    int getModel();
    void accelerate();
    void brake();


};

int Car::getSpeed()
{

    return speed;
}

Car::Car(int yearModel, string make, int speed = 0)

{

}

void Car::accelerate()
{
    speed += 5;
}

void Car::brake()
{
    if (speed > 5)
        speed -= 5;
    else speed = 0;
}


int main()
{
    int yearModel;
    string make;
    cout << "Enter year and make ";

    cin >> yearModel >> make;

    Car myCar(yearModel, make);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myCar.accelerate();
        cout << "The speed of the car is: " << myCar.getSpeed() << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {

            myCar.brake();
            cout << "The speed of the car is " << myCar.getSpeed() << endl;

            system("PAUSE");
            return (0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor doesn't initialize any of the member variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
Car::Car(int yearModel, string make, int speed = 0)
{

}
```

You have an empty constructor body that does nothing. Hence after the object is constructed, its data members will:

```
int yearModel;     // Have Undefined value
string make;       // Have Default initialized value
int speed;         // Have Undefined value
```

You should initialize them in your constructor initializer list:

```
Car::Car(int YearModel, string Make, int Speed = 0)
   : yearModel(YearModel), make(Make), speed(Speed)
{

}
```

Comment: I fixed that part, but the speed still only accelerates until 5 and brakes to 0, no matter what model year or make I input